# Does Code in onRequestPermissionsResult / onActivityResult run on UI thread anyway?

Tags: android, multithreading

Does Code in onRequestPermissionsResult run on UI thread anyway, even if requestPermissions was called on a non-UI thread?

Furthermore, do all callback methods of Activity act like this? Such as onActivityResult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callbacks like that run on the UI thread, yes.

If you request permissions asynchronously, Android starts its own internal Activity to deal with that. That essentially nullifies your new Thread, since new components aren't run in the Thread that requested they be created (they're usually run on the main Thread).

Once the permissions request process is done, the internal Activity sets its result, which is sent back to your Activity through the Android framework. Nothing is directly invoked, so the original Thread is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: One more question. requestPermissions will show a dialogue, thus it manipulates UI. Calling requestPermissions on a non-UI thread will cause some problem?

Comment: Like I said, `requestPermissions` starts an internal Activity. That Activity runs on the UI thread no matter where you call `requestPermissions` from.

Comment: So the permission request dialogue actually belongs to the internal Acitivity?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise there would be no data returned in `onActivityResult` and you'd be using a listener instead.

Comment: But for requestPermissions, the return data is dealt with onRequestPermissionsResult, not onActivityResult.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong method. It's the same idea though.

Comment: I understand your meaning. Thanks again.